# how can i make this custom path on flutter.Line,quadratic etc custom clipper,clip path

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

how can i make this custom clipper ?
i cant make it with border radius.Can anyone send code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Path

```dart
class CardClipperPath extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  final double curveRadius;

  CardClipperPath({this.curveRadius = 16.0});

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) => Path()
    ..quadraticBezierTo(0, curveRadius * .75, curveRadius, curveRadius)
    ..lineTo(size.width - curveRadius, curveRadius)
    ..quadraticBezierTo(size.width, curveRadius, size.width, curveRadius * 2)
    ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
    ..lineTo(0, size.height);

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CardClipperPath oldClipper) => oldClipper != this;
}
```

[image]

Wrap with Stack and provide corner image.